Need hints, GTK3 fails on Windows but runs fine in Ubuntu
could anyone with experiences working with GTK3 give me some hint on how to tackle this obscure crash related to progress bar update?
I have built a GTK3 application on Ubuntu and cross compiled it with MSYS2 MINGW64 for Windows. I uses libarchive to compute digest of some zip files and during the computation, I have callbacks to update the GtkProgressBar
static void progress_cb(int percentage, GtkParm text)
{
    GtkWidget *bar = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "progress_bar");
    if (progressbar && G_IS_OBJECT(bar))
    {
       gtk_progress_bar_set_text(bar, text);
       gtk_progress_bar_set_fraction(bar, percentage);
       gtk_widget_set_visible(bar, true);
    }
};


Then in my other threaded function, I have something like this:
gpointer thread_func(gpointer arg)
{
    MyObject test;
    test.set_progress_callback(progress_cb);
    test.do_work();
}

When I run the code, everything works fine in Linux/Ubuntu, even when I process large 2GB files, however in Windows, the progress reporting would only work for small files, trying to run process the large file would result in segmenetation fault somewhere within libgtk-3-0.dll.
Thread 1 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffad43fefb5 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgtk-3-0.dll
(gdb) where
#0  0x00007ffad43fefb5 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgtk-3-0.dll
#1  0x00007ffad41bca2d in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgtk-3-0.dll
#2  0x00007ffad42f389c in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgtk-3-0.dll
#3  0x00007ffad41b6b36 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgtk-3-0.dll
#4  0x00007ffad41bca14 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgtk-3-0.dll
#5  0x00007ffad42f38c1 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgtk-3-0.dll
#6  0x00007ffad44057d8 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgtk-3-0.dll
#7  0x00007ffad41b0724 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgtk-3-0.dll
#8  0x00007ffad41b0844 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgtk-3-0.dll
#9  0x00007ffad415c6a4 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgtk-3-0.dll
#10 0x00007ffad41b6b36 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgtk-3-0.dll
#11 0x00007ffad41bca14 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgtk-3-0.dll
#12 0x00007ffad415da41 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgtk-3-0.dll
#13 0x00007ffad44057d8 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgtk-3-0.dll
#14 0x00007ffad41b0724 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgtk-3-0.dll
#15 0x00007ffad41b0844 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgtk-3-0.dll
#16 0x00007ffad44057d8 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgtk-3-0.dll
#17 0x00007ffad440f5a4 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgtk-3-0.dll
#18 0x00007ffad429cbc0 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgtk-3-0.dll
#19 0x00007ffb16e9f769 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgdk-3-0.dll
#20 0x00007ffb16eaf3eb in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgdk-3-0.dll
#21 0x00007ffb16eb1106 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgdk-3-0.dll
#22 0x00007ffb16eb130b in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgdk-3-0.dll
#23 0x00007ffb50368654 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgobject-2.0-0.dll
#24 0x00007ffb5037d7bf in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgobject-2.0-0.dll
#25 0x00007ffb50383509 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgobject-2.0-0.dll
#26 0x00007ffb16ea9157 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgdk-3-0.dll
#27 0x00007ffb16e93102 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgdk-3-0.dll
#28 0x00007ffb16a645da in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libglib-2.0-0.dll
#29 0x00007ffb16a6082f in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libglib-2.0-0.dll
#30 0x00007ffb16a637b3 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libglib-2.0-0.dll
#31 0x00007ffb16a64140 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libglib-2.0-0.dll
#32 0x00007ffad429bb1e in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgtk-3-0.dll
#33 0x00007ff64d98f797 in main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>) at test.cc:1133
(gdb) up
#1  0x00007ffad41bca2d in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgtk-3-0.dll
(gdb) up
#2  0x00007ffad42f389c in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgtk-3-0.dll
(gdb) q

I am able to process the entire 2GB+ file in Windows as long as is not involved GTK progress bar update... A couple more questions I'd like to ask:

Is there some kind of known limitation in Windows?
Would updating the UI it too frequently cause GTK to crash?

I did ran valgrind in Linux and observed that there were memory leak within glib (not from my code though) itself during the run.
==6830== LEAK SUMMARY:
==6830==    definitely lost: 22,528 bytes in 33 blocks
==6830==    indirectly lost: 91,703 bytes in 3,626 blocks
==6830==      possibly lost: 6,416 bytes in 73 blocks
==6830==    still reachable: 5,208,045 bytes in 58,399 blocks
==6830==                       of which reachable via heuristic:
==6830==                         newarray           : 72,480 bytes in 15 blocks

Those leaks mainly came from the following:
{
   <insert_a_suppression_name_here>
   Memcheck:Leak
   match-leak-kinds: definite
   fun:malloc
   fun:g_malloc
   obj:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.7200.4
   obj:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.7200.4
   fun:call_init.part.0
   fun:call_init
   fun:_dl_init
   obj:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
}


Fix the memory leaks first.   I currently use the GTK3 library on Linux, Windows and MacOS.   There's not enough information here to track down what your issue is.  Make the assumption that you are just getting lucky on Linux. Use the address sanitizer on Linux to track down the memory issues -- it's easier to use than valgrind.

Are you trying to update the UI from another thread? That is not supported and could cause the crashes you're seeing.

Yeah, I was updating the UI from the thread, in the end, I had to do some ghetto static/global variable to hold the data, then after exiting the thread, I would tell the UI to read the static var instead... ugly, but that's the only way I got it to work for now. Thanks!
